# Replicating the enqueue() method

Tags: kotlin, okhttp

I have the following method which simply fetches the data in ether SYNC or ASYNC way:

```
enum class CallType { SYNC, ASYNC }

suspend fun get( url: String, callType : CallType, mock : String? = null, callback: Callback? ): Response?
{
    var response : okhttp3.Response ?= null

    val request = Request.Builder()
        .url( url )
        .build()

    val call = client.newCall( request )

    if( mock != null )
    {
        // this works fine for SYNC, but how to make it work with ASYNC callback?
        delay( 1000 )
        return okhttp3.Response.Builder().body(
            ResponseBody.create( "application/json".toMediaType(), mock )
        ).build()
    }

    if( callType == CallType.ASYNC && callback != null )
        call.enqueue( callback )
    else
        response = call.execute()

    return response
}
```

I would like to be able to mock/overwrite the response. I can do this fine when doing it the SYNC way, since I simply have to construct and return a fake okhttp3.response, like the snippet below, and the code execution stops and everything works out great:

```
    if( mock != null )
    {
        delay( 1000 )
        return okhttp3.Response.Builder().body(
            ResponseBody.create( "application/json".toMediaType(), mock )
        ).build()
    }
```

The problem is that I would like to be able to do the same for ASYNC calls, but I'm not sure where to go from here. I'm basically trying to replicate the enqueue() method so that after some delay my callback gets triggered (which was passed to the get() method) and my fake okhttp3.Response is returned via the callback, instead of *return*. Any suggestions on how to accomplish this? Thanks!

Comment: What is `client` here? Where did you get it from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing different concepts with your implementation. Asynchrony should be controlled with the `CoroutineContext` instead of parameters. Like this you'll always return a non-null value. Also it's wise to hide the implementation details (here *OkHttp*) and not expose it.

You could use `suspendCoroutine` to bridge *OkHttp* with the couroutine.

```
suspend fun get(
    url: String,
    mock : String? = null
) = if(mock != null) {
    delay( 1000 )
    Response.Builder().body(
        ResponseBody.create(
            "application/json".toMediaType()
            mock
        )
    ).build()
} else suspendCoroutine { continuation ->
    client.newCall(
        Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .build()
    ).enqueue(
        object : Callback {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) =
                continuation.resumeWithException(e)
            override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) =
                continuation.resume(response)
        }
    )
}
```

To access it synchronously just use

```
runBlocking { get(url, mock) }
```

If you really need to provide your own `Callable`, you could easily delegate to it. But you'd also have to create a call, even though you wouldn't need it when you're mocking the response.

Answer (score 1):

one easy way is to just call the callback in a synchronous way:

```
if (mock != null) {
  val response = ... // prepare mock response here
  callback.onResponse(response)
}
```

in consequence the callback would be invoked even before your get function finishes.

If you want to achieve that the response actually is delivered asynchronously you need to execute the mock delivery from an extra coroutine

```
if (mock != null) {
   GlobalScope.launch {
      val response = ... // prepare mock response here
      delay(1000)
      callback.onResponse(response)
   }
}
```